# How can I remove a package completely?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I'm unable to remove the package `python3-pip` in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ apt list |& grep 'python3-pip/'
python3-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all
$ sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3-pip' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
openstack@prclnx04:~/python/pybind11$ apt list |& grep 'python3-pip/'
python3-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3-pip
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove python3-pip which isn't installed
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3-pip
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove python3-pip which isn't installed
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
$ apt list |& grep 'python3-pip/'           
python3-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all
$ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3-pip' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ apt list |& grep 'python3-pip/'           
python3-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all
```

Is there a way to force `apt` to completely remove the package?

**Edit 1:**

```
$ apt policy python3-pip
python3-pip:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4
  Version table:
     8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 500
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
     8.1.1-2 500
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
     1.5.4-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe i386 Packages
$ apt list |& grep 'python3-pip/'
python3-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all
$

$ apt list --installed | grep python3-pip

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

$ dpkg --get-selections | grep python3-pip
$ apt list |& grep 'python3-pip/'
python3-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 all
$
```

Comment: What does `apt list --installed | grep python3-pip` return?

Comment: @cl-netbox Yep, that works too.  My comment here is based on the command that is being run.  The one part that is missing from OPs command is the `--installed`.  The command of `list` lists all packages regardless of being installed or not.

Comment: python3-pip is not installed on the computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check whether the package is installed :

```
$ apt policy python3-pip
python3-pip:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.1.2-2ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
     8.1.2-2ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe i386 Packages
     8.1.2-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe i386 Packages
```

In case it is (in this example it's  not) execute :

```
sudo apt purge python3-pip
```

In case you mistakenly chose the wrong one :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep python3
```

You get a list of installed `python3` packages.

**Clarification** and general information : Your Edit 1 output shows that the package is not installed and hence it cannot be removed. The `apt list` command shows available packages, it does NOT show installed packages, unless you add `--installed` to the `apt list` command as mentioned in the comment from @Terrance. And, be very careful which packages you remove as pointed out by @ByteCommander ... `sudo apt purge` completely removes packages and configuration files !

Comment: If you look at *edit 1*, you see that the package doesn't seem to be installed, but still, it appears in the `apt list` output.

Comment: @boardrider The apt list command shows **available** packages ... NOT installed packages. :)

Comment: Just a side note, **make sure you do not accidentally remove the complete `python3`** if you want your system to remain usable. Only remove module packages for Python 3 which you manually installed yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When packages are listed with flags 'ic' in `dpkg -l` then they can't be removed with apt, but you have to use `dpkg -P <package>`.